# Yoneda's Lemma in Vakil's notes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

[Vakil's Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ksTv.jpg)

in the exercise 1.3Y, what does 1.3.10.2 commutes with the maps 1.3.10.1 mean? I can't see any relation between 1.3.10.1 and 1.3.10.2.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE. __2__ things: For questions of this nature it is mandatory that you show some working or at least your thoughts on how to get to the solution, and secondly, if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. All the best.

Comment: Contrary to the downvotes and the comment above, this is a perfectly reasonable question with plenty of context provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that given any two objects $B$ and $C$ and a map $f:B\to C$, the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Mor}(C,A) @>{i_C}>> \operatorname{Mor}(C,A')\\
@V{}VV @V{}VV \\
\operatorname{Mor}(B,A) @>{i_B}>> \operatorname{Mor}(B,A')
\end{CD}$$
commutes, where the vertical maps are given by 1.3.10.1 via $f$.  Note that in 1.3.10.2, you are supposed to have a map $i_C:\operatorname{Mor}(C,A)\to \operatorname{Mor}(C,A')$ for *each* object $C$; in this diagram we are using two of these maps (for $C$ and for $B$).